# Capybara wit RSpec Unable to find field "Nombre del cliente" that is not disabled

Tags: rspec, capybara

I'm working in a C# app making an automated test with Capybara and RSpec (for resasons...) when i use fill_in like this

fill_in 'Nombre del cliente', with: "user name 123"

the console said

Failure/Error: fill_in 'Nombre del cliente', with: "1365"

```
 Capybara::ElementNotFound:
   Unable to find field "Nombre del cliente" that is not disabled
```

the full HTML of the selector is:

```
<div class="col-md-2">

   <label>Cliente:</label>
   <input type="text" ng-model="clienteSeleccionado" placeholder="Nombre del cliente" class="form-control ng-pristine ng-valid ng-empty ng-touched" uib-typeahead="cliente as cliente.Nombre for cliente in clientesFiltrados($viewValue)" typeahead-loading="cargandoClientes" typeahead-no-results="noResults" typeahead-on-select="clienteTypeaheaad($item, $model, $label, $event)" typeahead-min-length="3" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-expanded="false" aria-owns="typeahead-5-6227"><ul class="dropdown-menu ng-isolate-scope ng-hide" ng-show="isOpen() &amp;&amp; !moveInProgress" ng-style="{top: position().top+'px', left: position().left+'px'}" role="listbox" aria-hidden="true" uib-typeahead-popup="" id="typeahead-5-6227" matches="matches" active="activeIdx" select="select(activeIdx, evt)" move-in-progress="moveInProgress" query="query" position="position" assign-is-open="assignIsOpen(isOpen)" debounce="debounceUpdate">
   <!-- ngRepeat: match in matches track by $index -->
   </ul>
   <i ng-show="cargandoClientes" class="fa fa-refresh ng-hide"></i>
   <div ng-show="noResults" class="ng-hide">
       <i class="fa fa-remove"></i> Cliente no encontrado
   </div>
   <i class="fa fa-remove ng-hide" ng-show="clienteSeleccionado" ng-click="clienteS

eleccionado = null; getPage()"></i>
</div>
```

I tried different things. Any idea?
Thx

Comment: You need to format your question differently -- the html isn't showing - but looking at the source of your question and all the classes on the input - I'm guessing that isn't the actual element that is visible on the users page, and instead it''s being replace by some autocomplete/typeahead widget - that is the element you would need to call `fill_in` on